# Definition of independent random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In [Terrence Tao's notes,](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/#fp)he made the following definition

> **Definition 16:** A collection $(X_i)_{i \in A}$ of random variables $X_i$ is said to be *jointly independent* if satisfies one of the following
>
> 1. the distribution $(X_i)_{i \in A}$ is the product of distributions of the $X_i$.
> 2. $$ P( \bigwedge_{i \in B} (X_i \in S_i) ) = \prod_{i \in B} P(X_i \in S_i).$$ 
>      for all finite sets $B \subseteq A$, and measurable set $S_i$ of $R_i$.

I don't understand definition 1. *What is it written out explicitly?* No where does he defines the distribution of $(X_i)_{i \in A}$. Suppose we regard $(X_i)_i : \Omega \rightarrow \prod R_i$. I *guess* definition 1 is :

> **Definition'** $X_i$ are independent iff for all measurable $S \subseteq \prod R_i$, 
>   $$ P((X_i)_i \in S ) = \prod P\Big((X_i) \in \pi_i(S)\Big). $$

This results in two questions.

1. I don't know how this makes sense as the product on RHS is infinite.
2. How would this be equivalent to the second formulation (note $S$ is not a product set here ).

Comment: Distribution of a random variable is just the probability of every possible event, so just the numbers $P(X_i\in S_i)$ for all $S_i$ measurable. (Event is another word for a measurable set).

Comment: $X=(X_i)_{i\in A}$ is a random variable itself: it has a probability distribution.

Comment: @ClementC., i have written out my concerns regarding this.

Comment: The formula in your update is wrong. $$\mathbb{P}\{ X \in S \} = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_i \{X_i \in \pi_i(S)\} \right)$$ which is **not** equal to the product in general. (That's... when the $X_i$'s are independent.)

Comment: The equation i wrote was what it means to be independent. So $P(\bigcap X_i \in \pi_i(S) ) = \prod P(X_i \in \pi_i(S))$ iff $X_i$ are independent. So the two questions I wrote follow - most of the things make sense in finite case, but I don't understand infinite case. I hope the edit is clearer.

Comment: @ClementC., I edited my post to explain my confusions .